# Is there any method to execute a robot test on a separate remote windows machine?

Tags: robotframework, remote-execution

I am trying to execute a robot test containing AutoTtLibrary. This test is executed locally on the PC but now I am trying to execute the same test on that PC but invoked from different PC.

1. I used remoterunner library. While test started, I got error that AutoItLibrary.py access is denied.
2. I used PsEXEC to launch cmd of remote PC, and then tried to execute the same robot command on this cmdline which worked on the local PC. The test started but it got stuck.

Is there any method to resolve this issue?

Right now my only option is to execute robot test on each pc locally

Answer (score 0):

robotremoteserver .. install/setup it and required keyword libraries and then modify your `Library`'s to point to that remote host.

More info here: https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer

Also here is a blog post that might give more details: https://xebia.com/blog/the-robot-framework-remote-library-interface-using-the-remote-database-library-to-connect-to-ibm-db2/ -- it talks about databases but its essentially the same idea.

Comment: I am not sure, but with remote library only the keywords that will be executed on the remote server but the test itself not.

Comment: @BenceKaulics OP said "execute the same test on that PC but invoked from different PC."  ..  That doesn't clarify what the "execute the test" means.   robot instance could be where the "invocation" happens and actual testing, not running the robot coud on the remote.

Comment: Another scenario is that op would just need an ssh on the remote box with, and start the robot via it (but also making sure desktop is open and ssh has access to it - which can be issue if you are not aware of what needs to be done) ..

Comment: Yes, the remoteserver library exposes library keywords on the pc acting as server. Then the pc which is DUT is where robot executes the test. If the remote server library is integrated in the test to be run, then the test will be executed locally on that pc but the keywords will be from remote server.

Comment: What i meant was that there is a test suite t1.robot that I developed on the pc pc1 and  executed it on the same pc pc1.

Comment: My requirement is that I need to execute the same test suite t1.robot on several pcs such that execution is triggered from a central pc to all pcs pc1 pc2 pc3 etc.

Comment: @sakshimishra well, depends .. the easiest way would be to just setup something like jenkins do that for you